# Phoneagr capture and process audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, cordova

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to capture and process audio in realtime. Essentially I want to create an app that changes the pitch of a users voice and I'm not sure whether this is possible in phonegap or is it best to build in native code ie objective-c.

Thanks

Comment: Well I don't know if there is an html5 api to do this, but anyway I think is better for you to look either for an existing cordova ios plugin or to build it yourself